# Django, AWS EB ERROR, Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-wsgi

I have been trying to deploy my project with AWS EB console, not CLI, and I have encountered this "Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist." again and again. I changed the WSGIPath from application.py to awesomedonor/wsgi.py and I struggled to find typo in my django.config but I failed...So... I need you guys help!!
[image]

this is my EB status,

[image]

this is django.config. and last...
[image]

This is list of files and directory I try to upload, except venv, db.sqlite, and zip file.

Comment: Try awesomedonor/ in the path

Comment: you mean WSGIPath in EB?? In that case, I already changed it from application.py to awesomedonor/wsgi.py...ㅠㅠ

Answer (score 0):

It feels like the zip file does not contain the right structure. Please download the application version from EB console and unzip to ensure it contains the following structure.

```
....manage.py
....requirements.txt
....awesomedonor
........wsgi.py
```

hope this helps.